# How to get the counter value for a reference?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, arithmetic

The command `\label{here}` defines a label and `\ref{here}` outputs the corresponding representation in the text. Is it possible to get the correspondig (numeric) counter value for the `here` reference so that one could do calculations with it and use it to set a counter, for example?